# Empty permissions while trying to get list of the permission on the specific file id

Tags: java, google-drive-api

I'm using GDrive Java API and trying to get list of permissions on the specific file id and getting empty response, means list = null.
I'm calling list request, as it shown in the google documentation example:

```
 PermissionList permissions = service.permissions().list(fileId).execute();
```

The permissions.getItems() is null, when there is no permissions for the specific file ?

Thanks

Comment: It should not be `null`. On the bottom of this page https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/permissions/list you can find `APIs Explorer`, try it to load permissions for this file. `Java API` should return the same result which returns `APIs Explorer`.

Comment: Should not be, but it's and in the Gdrive SDK for the permissions this is a documentation :  com.google.api.services.drive.model.PermissionList.getItems()

The actual list of permissions.

Returns:
value or null for none.